# Web Service call from AJAX, service not found

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, iis

I have a web method that gets kicked off with an AJAX call here is my web method:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
 public void ProcessAddress(Dictionary<string, string> Header, bool AddrValues)
 {

    _service.ProcessNoMatchModal(Header, AddrValues);
 }
```

which is called from this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../Services/Address.asmx/ProcessAddress",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function() { 
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: function() { },
        asynch: false
    });
```

What is more confusing is I have two virtual directories that are pointing to the same code source and for the first this service works and is available but for the second it does not work and I see a 404 in firebug

Any leads/suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

[From  Here:](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx)

> 1. The method MUST be static
> 2. The method needs to be decorated with [WebMethod()]
> 3. The method needs to be decorated with [ScriptMethod()] if you want to make a ASP.NET AJAX callback to it

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an 404 http error I would blame the relative path reference you've made (with the double dot) in the url setting.

From your first location you call the webservice with the correct path, from the second you are targeting a wrong path... Try looking at the actual path you are calling using Fiddler or Chrome Developer Tools to see if I'm correct.

If you call this function from virtual directories with different depths you would probably be better off without a relative path reference but start at the root..
One of the following should work I guess:

```
url: "Services/Address.asmx/ProcessAddress"
url: document.location.hostname + "/Services/Address.asmx/ProcessAddress"
```